# Assignment operator overloading -- error C2440: '==' : cannot convert from 'A<T> *' to 'A<T> *const '

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

The following codes try to show how to overload assignment operator:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A()   {};
    A( T &obj) {value = obj;};
    ~A() {};
    T value;

    template <typename E>
    A<T>& operator = ( A<E> &obj)
    {

        if(this == &obj)
            return *this;

        value = obj.value;
        return *this;
    }

};



int main()
{
    int temp;
    temp = 3;
    A<int> myobjects(temp);
    cout<<myobjects.value<<endl;

     float f_value;
     f_value = 10.7;
     A<float> fobjects(f_value);
     myobjects = fobjects;
     cout<<myobjects.value<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile it with VC10, I have found the following error:

```
 error C2440: '==' : cannot convert from 'A<T> *' to 'A<T> *const '
```

If I change the overloading function in the following way:

```
  template <typename E>
    A<T>& operator = ( A<E> &obj)
    {

     // if(this == &obj)
        //  return *this;

        value = obj.value;
        return *this;
    }
```

It will work.  Why does this error occur in the commented-out code when called in this way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399832/why-operator-overloading-fails

Comment: @crashmstr, he's not, he's using the `==` operator to check for object identity before doing assignment.

Comment: This was already answered in your previous question's comments. Take a minute to read over the answers and comments. Hint, since `T` and `E` cannot be the same type, that test will never be `true`.

Comment: This sub-question has also been answered in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399832/why-operator-overloading-fails

Comment: @Hans: "how to use *equal* operator". He is having problems with an equality check, but he is **confusing** the *assignment* operator overloading with *equal* operator overloading. In other words, the title and first sentence of the question is what I was commenting on.

Comment: Why isn't your argument a const reference?

Comment: @crashmstr no he's being **confusing**, he knows where the `==` is being used, as he has commented out the relevant code section, but his use of the phrase "how to use equal operator" can either be misconstrued to mean `=` or `==`. you are the one **confused**.

Comment: @dribeas: Are you sure?  Is something preventing a partial specialization of `A<E>` from inheriting `A<T>` or vice-versa (for some particular combination of `E` and `T`)?

Comment: @Hans: No, the compiler-provided copy assignment operator will be called whenever the argument is a `A<T>`.

Comment: @Hans, here is the original text: "*Equal operator overloading*
The following codes try to show how to use equal operator overloading function:". Ben has made the title and text fit the problem, but the poster may not understand the difference in terminology, which may cause confusion later.

Comment: @crashmstr: The original text was ambiguous.  Does "equal operator" mean assignment operator (`=`) or equality operator (`==`)?  He clearly meant assignment operator (the only one being overloaded).

Comment: Thanks, and now I got it. The reason why I put another poster rather than continue with my previous one is because I thought these were two different questions. Now I understand that I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing part of the error message.  It should say:

```
error C2440: '==' : cannot convert from 'A<T> *' [with T = float] to 'A<T> *const' [with T = int]
```

You may have to look at nearby lines in the build log to see that extra information.  And the compiler is doing no favors by using `T` twice but representing two different types.